# htaccess deny from breaks environmental variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website which setup as described. The site root level has a htaccess file which is used to deny bad bots and users using something like

```
Allow from all
Deny from x.x.x.x
```

I have another htaccess file off the root level, which is used to define my environment variables for the my database.

For some reason unknown to me, when an IP is blocked, the website reports

```
Access denied for user 'example.com'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: NO)
```

This only happens when I try to block a user. Is there a way to pass the environment variables under  restricted permissions?

Thanks

Comment: This is definitely weird to put database ENV in your htaccess

Comment: Where would you suggest storing database details?

Comment: The best practice is to put those data in a file out of public scope (in a PHP file or INI file for instance) and to call it from server script

Comment: Would that not be the same as the htaccess file?

Comment: Definetely not. There are many way of doing it but your idea (with htaccess) is not a good one, sorry

Comment: Can you give an example?